# How do I create a bitcoin payment request?

Tags: request, payment, bitcoin

I'd like to be able to programmatically create a bitcoin payment request per [BIP 0070](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0070.mediawiki) and email it to someone for payment.

What are the libraries, web services, or code samples I should be looking at to figure this out?

Comment: Not sure about "bip 0070" but you could always use coinbase.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't implemented it yet, but Gavin Andresen has a repository with what looks like a c++ and PHP implementation. I'll check it out later and post a code sample here when I get it working.

https://github.com/gavinandresen/paymentrequest

This has both a c++ and php implementation. the c++ code has a paymentrequest-create and a paymentrequest-dump. create creates the payment and dump verifies it. Use the project Readmes to compile and to understand usage.